# BF action as difference of Chern-Simons terms

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, chern-simons-theory

I believe this boils down to lack of familiarity on my part with wedge products of forms, but I've been looking at https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505027, and the idea that the [BF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BF_model) action

$$S_{BF} = \int_M tr (B\wedge F + \frac{\kappa^2}{3} B\wedge B\wedge B)$$

can be written as proportional to the difference of [Chern-Simons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Simons_theory) terms, i.e. $$2\kappa S_{BF} = (1/2)(S_{CS}(A+\kappa B) - S_{CS}(A-\kappa B))$$ where
$$
S_{CS}(A) = \int_M tr (A\wedge dA + \frac{2}{3} A\wedge A\wedge A)
$$
So, when I expand this out, the factor of $2\kappa$ is easy to obtain. Thankfully I know enough about exterior derivatives to recognise that $dA=F$. There's also an extra term proportional to:

$$tr(A\wedge A\wedge B + A\wedge B\wedge A + B\wedge A\wedge A) \ .$$

If this were an ordinary product of matrices, the cyclic nature of the trace would mean that the three terms are equal and I'd get:

$$3 tr A\wedge A\wedge B \ .$$

What's the right way to see that this actually goes to zero (as it must, to get the result)? Also, it seems there's a factor of two I haven't accounted for, which is getting me:

$$\frac{2\kappa^2}{3}$$ instead of: $$\frac{\kappa^2}{3}$$ in the difference of CS (Chern-Simons) actions. What am I overlooking? I'm sure it's something minor, like I said, just a matter of familiarity.

===**Edit**===

I've adjusted the second equation, above, by adding a factor of (1/2) in line with d_b's comment, however this still leaves a discrepancy I'm confused by. The first terms give
$$ (1/2)\left(\int_M tr(A+\kappa B)\wedge dA -\int_M tr(A-\kappa B)\wedge dA\right) = (1/2)\int_M tr(2\kappa B\wedge dA) = \kappa\int_M tr(B\wedge F) 
$$
but the paper I'm looking at claims the factor out front should be $2\kappa$ (which I **do** get for the $B^3$ term), rather than just $\kappa$. And I'm still not sure about the right way to argue that the terms cyclic in $A\wedge A\wedge B$ sum to zero.

Comment: Small comment: note the factor of 1/2 in Eq. 6 of the linked reference.

Comment: Good point, thank you. I've edited my post accordingly. However it doesn't really resolve the issue - there's still a discrepancy of a factor of 2 between the $B\wedge F$ term and the $B^3$ term, to get the correct form of the BF action.